# Remove All NVIDIA Files

Tags: ubuntu, nvidia, cinnamon, uninstall

**Background**: I bought an NVIDIA graphics card and tried to install its driver. Somewhere along the way I messed up and now I'm running my computer on Cinnamon backup mode (I have Ubuntu but I removed Unity and replaced it with Cinnamon). I want to start back from scratch (prior to this, I was using a core i3 and no graphics card).

**Problem**:
When I enter `sudo dpkg -l | grep -i nvidia` I get a list of results:

[image: Results]

But when I enter `sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*` it says I have no matches found.

I've tried a couple of other different ways with similar results. Again, I want to start fresh by removing all unnecessary files.

How do I remove all unnecessary nvidia files?

Comment: Do you need to escape the `*` in your remove command?  `sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-\*`

Comment: I agree with @drs. It's quite possible that your shell is expanding the `*` before it even gets to `apt-get`. Escape it or quote it, and try again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not particularly useful here (where you can just fix your escaping as commented) but in the case where you want to search the whole `dpkg -l` line, you can run it through something like `awk` and then into `apt-get purge` with minimal conditioning:

```
sudo apt-get purge $(dpkg -l | awk '$2~/nvidia/ {print $2}')
```

That should prompt you before it does anything but just in case, you could test it with:

```
apt-get -s purge $(dpkg -l | awk '$2~/nvidia/ {print $2}')
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `*` is being expanded by your shell *before* it is passed to `apt-get`. You probably have a file or directory in your current directory whose name starts with `nvidia-` and that is being passed to `apt-get`. To illustrate:

```
$ ls -l
-rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon 0 Jul 16 17:22 nvidia-foo

$ sudo apt-get -s purge nvidia-*
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package nvidia-foo
```

That's because what is actually being run is `sudo apt-get -s purge nvidia-foo` since `nvidia-*` is expanded to `nvidia-foo` before being passed to `apt-get`. This is why you should always quote your globs:

```
$ sudo apt-get -s purge 'nvidia-*'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have only access to GRUB:

1. Restart your computer
2. Select `Advanced options for Ubuntu` at GRUB Boot Menu
3. Select `Ubuntu ..... (recovery mode)`
4. Select `dpkg` Repair broken packages at the Recovery Menu (this will stop the nvidia processes so we can uninstall). Choose Yes. When finished press ENTER (even if it found problems)
5. Select `root` (Drop to root shell promt at the Recovery Menu)
6. Type your root password
7. Type: `apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*`
8. If finished type: `reboot`
9. Boot as usual, it should go to your Ubuntu Login screen now